# Meteor detect on client load if web socket connection failed

Tags: meteor, websocket, client

Is there a way to detect if the current client web socket connection has failed without installing extra tools, such as `wscat`?

In my case after a restart of my production app the first connection attempt fails to connect to the web socket, but a page reload does it.

In this case I would force my client to reload in order to regain a running web socket connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html

There is a method `Meteor.status()` which runs on the client and is a reactive data source, which means you can use it in a template or computation to get realtime updates.

If you detect a failure you shouldn't do anything straight away, most times the connection will automatically recover. You should wait a few seconds before taking action (like a refresh)

Comment: Thank you, after using it as reactive data source my client automatically refreshed on connection attempt.